# Applying a middleware function to particular requests

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I want to apply a particular middleware function to the two `post` requests but not the `get` request. How could I do this?

```
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

router.post('/jobs',(req,resp)=>{
  var messageString = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  Job.accept(messageString,(statusCode,respObject)=>{
    resp.status(statusCode).json(respObject);
  });
});

router.get('/jobs',(req,resp)=>{
  Job.status((statusCode,respObject)=>{     
      resp.status(statusCode).json(respObject);  
  });
});

router.post('/try',(req,resp)=>{
  var messageString = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  Job.ok(messageString,(statusCode,respObject)=>{
    resp.status(statusCode).json(respObject);
  });
});
```

I was reading about [app.use](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use), but couldn't really understand its usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the middleware you want to the function. Here is an example where I log the users IP

```
const myLogger = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('got a request from', req.connection.remoteAddress);
  next();
}

app.post('/jobs', myLogger, (req, res) => {
  //your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with the answer mentioned above, write `app.use(myLogger)`